# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string "Catch Fry's Low Impact''

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am in need to match string esacping single quotes. This is how my query looks like:

```
select  Distinct(a.item) 
from [dbo].[Subscribtions] a
where a.Item like 'Catch Fry''s Low Impact''
```

But it is throwing the error

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Catch Fry's Low Impact''.

I cannot use `like pattern matching%` there are multiple such string. For some data reason I have to go with `=` only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your query

```
select  Distinct(a.item) 
from [dbo].[Subscribtions] a
where a.Item like 'Catch Fry''s Low Impact''
```

You have an extra `'` in the last of `'Catch Fry''s Low Impact''`, also you don't need parentheses in `Distinct(a.item)`.

Since you are looking for `'Catch Fry''s Low Impact'` literally, the results of

```
select  Distinct a.item 
from [dbo].[Subscribtions] a
where a.Item like 'Catch Fry''s Low Impact';
```

will be the same as

```
select  Distinct a.item 
from [dbo].[Subscribtions] a
where a.Item = 'Catch Fry''s Low Impact';
```

So, I think you are just looking for

```
select  Distinct a.item 
from [dbo].[Subscribtions] a
where a.Item = 'Catch Fry''s Low Impact';
```

There is no benefit in using **[`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** operator unless you are doing wild card matching.